# Proving properties of ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> [image: desc]

I am having a hard time proving question b. Here is my attempt on both a and b:

a:
Let x be in S and a be in the Integers. Then, for all x, we may fix a = -1. Therefore, -x is in S.

b:
The problem I am having is that I simply do not know how to "construct" the integer scalar "a" from the three givens. I have thought about picking two numbers sx and tx and then adding: sx + tx = (s + t)x    where s, t are integers and a = s + t. It just doesn't feel right.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MathSE! There are a few things you can do to spruce up your question to more easily help future visitors of the site. (1) Could you type out the question that's included in the image (otherwise the search indexer can't use that as text. (2) Could you [use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/167197) to format the math stuff in your post? It makes for easier reading.

Comment: I'll put in the time to learn MathJax so I can type both the question and formal mathematical writing in my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that for positive $a$ 
$$
ax = \underbrace{x+x+\dotsb+x}_{a \text{ times}}\,.
$$
All you need for that is (iii). Then you use (ii) in the case that $a$ is negative, and use (i) in the case that $a=0$.

Comment: I see. So you use (iii) over and over until you  have "a" terms of x. If you wanted a negative number, you use (ii) and if you want zero you use (i). I get it now, cant believe it was that simple I spent so long on it. Thank you.

Comment: @math_wizard1 Yeah, don't sweat it. Proving some of those "simple" things can be really tough to see sometime. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a$ is positive and work by induction on $a$.  Statement $(iv)$ is obviously true for $a=1.$

Now assume that $\forall x \in S, nx \in S.$  Then $nx+x=(n+1)x$ is the sum of two elements of $S$, so property $(iii)$ tells us that sum also is in $S$.  By induction, this proves that $ax \in S$ for any $a \gt 0$.

If $a \lt 0$, then $-a \gt 0$ so we have just proved above that $-ax \in S$, and property $(ii)$ tells us that $- (-ax) = ax \in S$.

Finally, if $a=0$, then property $(1)$ tells us $0x=0 \in S$.

Thus, for any $a \in \Bbb Z$ and for arbitrary $x \in S$, we have $ax \in S$.